# Generating a group count of user related entries in Craft CMS

Tags: twig

I have a Craft CMS site where users have a christmas "wish list" where they can add / remove items.

At the moment I have:

- A wish list entries section
- Users `wishListItems` matrix field containing a number of selected wish list entries

I know I can get a total count of all items specific to a single user with:

```
{% set userEntries = craft.users.username('buddy').first.wishListEntries.total() %}
```

But how can I list the most popular wish list items selected by all users?

Comment: Too vague. how are these items stored?  If you stored them textual in a table with `user_id`, `item` you could do a `SELECT count(item) FROM wishlist GROUP BY item`, do note this is prone to typing errors though

Comment: Thanks @DarkBee, I didn't consider using a table. Re how are the items stored, do you mean the wish list items? They are entries within a structure as to allow users to only add pre-defined wish list items to a wishlist. So under each user I have a matrix field which contains these entries as a related field (wishlist entry). Hope that makes sense?

Comment: In the end I created a new section to store the wishlistEntries and then select them by authorId, so can do a count on the total grouped by title and display selections per user.